# sequelize require typeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to add sequelize orm to my EMPTY project, and something goes wrong. The first thing I do is creating empty project by `express-generator`, next I'm write `npm install --save sequelize` and `npm install --save pg pg-hstore`. Then, in fresh generated files i add only one line `require('sequelize');` and I receive an error:

```
e:\nodeproj\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils\validator-extras.js:78
  validator.extend(key, extend);
            ^
TypeError: Object  has no method 'extend'
    at module.exports.extensions (e:\nodeproj\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils\validator-extras.js:78:13)
    at e:\nodeproj\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4040:15
    at baseForOwn (e:\nodeproj\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:2573:24)
    at e:\nodeproj\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4009:18
    at Function.forEach (e:\nodeproj\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:7634:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\nodeproj\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils\validator-extras.js:77:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\nodeproj\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

I've tried different versions, but result the same. Thank you in advance!

**UPD:**

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nodeproj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "node-sass-middleware": "0.8.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "sequelize": "~3.20.0",
    "pg-hstore": "~2.3.2",
    "pg": "~4.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you paste your package.json file?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg, sure.

Comment: Share your [app|server|index].js